# Ear dependency profile

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, ear

I am trying to deploy an EAR to JBOSS. There are many dependencies in ear. One of that is core java project which we assume that name is "CORE"
Spring core library was included into the CORE and CORE compiles java 1.7

I declared 2 profile definitions in the core project.default one name is compile17 another one compile18

CORE.pom

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>compile17</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>       
        <properties>
            <java.source>1.7</java.source>
            <java.target>1.7</java.target>
            <springframework.version>4.3.14.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>compile18</id>
        <properties>
            <java.source>1.8</java.source>
            <java.target>1.8</java.target>
            <springframework.version>4.3.25.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

EAR.pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>CORE</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

My question is as follows,How can I set the profile to active profile in the core.pom file when I get the ear file jboss a deploy.When I start openshift pipeline for deploy, Ear is deployed. I have two different platform so I need to select the CORE according to the appropriate platform

Comment: This cannot be done. You cannot activate profiles in  dependencies. Instead,  create two different core jars when building core.

Comment: That means also one EAR is only runnable on JDK 7 whereas the other one is only runnable on JDK 8 ...exactly what JF Meier wrote make two separate EAR's and two separate core jars....

Comment: I would like to get attention to something here, EAR is not ear file. "EAR" is another maven project that depends on all projects.ear file occurs when I build the "EAR project".I set the profile to compile18 when building EARproject so I expect the profile to be compile18 in core dependency.It is not possible to do this without creating 2 separate CORE jars?
thanks
JF Meier @khmarbaise

Comment: But you've talked about JBOSS which is an application server which can handle EAR files..and many dependencies in an EAR ?...confusing...If this dependency is one version build with JDK8 and one with JDK7 you have to have two EAR files as well cause otherwise this will fail on JBoss...

Comment: We don't use ear in same JBOSS.we use many different jboss clusters. We decided to compile CORE project 1.8 and use different spring subversion for some departments and we want to solve this with profile.So we aim to include the CORE project from nexus into your project and compile it in the profile you want.
thank you.
@khmarbaise

Comment: Bad idea to use profiles..but it's up to you...